# How to add second parameter in Select query in magento

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-1.8, magento-1.9, mysql

I try to retrieve some data using magento select.
Below is my coding.

```
Mage::app('default');
    $connection = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_read');
    $select = $connection->select()
                ->from('wired_points', array('*')) 
                ->where('order_id=?',$orderID);   

    //$rowsArray = $connection->fetchAll($select); // return all rows
    $rowArray =$connection->fetchRow($select);   //return rowe
```

I want to add one more condition in where like **log_id**.

**How can i add the second parameter to my where clause?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$select = $connection->select()
                ->from('wired_points', array('*')) 
                ->where('order_id=?',$orderID)
                ->where('log_id=?',$logId);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to add other with and condition then you can use below code:

```
$select = $connection->select()
            ->from('wired_points', array('*'))
            ->where('order_id=?',$orderID)
            ->where('log_id=?',$logId);
```

If you want to add "OR condition" then you can use below code:

```
$select = $connection->select()
            ->from('wired_points', array('*'))
            ->where('order_id=?',$orderID)
            ->orWhere('log_id=?',$logId);
```

Comment: Thank you,Its same as Rahul said and extra on adding an OR.

Answer (score 0):

mujas,it is `better process to Create new  model  for this table`.then you can used `Magento` [**collection functions**](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/1_-_installation_and_configuration/using_collections_in_magento)  on this  new module.Which will satisfy. You process is so sticky and very usefull   for quick works.

**Module Config.xml code look like:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Amit_Custommodule>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </Amit_Custommodule>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <custommodule>
                <class>Amit_Custommodule_Model</class>
                <resourceModel>custommodule_resource</resourceModel>
            </custommodule>
            <custommodule_resource>
                <class>Amit_Custommodule_Model_Resource</class>
                <entities>
                    <custommodule>
                        <table>wired_points</table>
                    </custommodule>
                </entities>
            </custommodule_resource>
        </models>
    </global>
</config>
```

And: Model can access via  `Mage::getModel("custommodule/custommodule")->getCollection();`

See more at My [Blog](http://www.amitbera.com/create-an-magento-extension-with-custom-database-table)

Also @Rahul Say,you can use `multiple where() as where clause`

Comment: Thank you,Have to study this method also.i used to read your blog